# Laravel Calendar scheduled dates

Tags: laravel, database, phpmyadmin, calendar, schedule

I have done my calendar module and all my schedules have been deleted from database and it happens randomly.
Anyone had this issue before?

Below is the only delete function I have. Is this the cause for it to be deleted?

```
// clear unbooked schedules within the time window
if ($r->has('clear') and $r->clear == 1) {
    $delete = Appointment::whereBetween('ts_start', [
        $ds,
        $de->copy()->addDay()->subSecond()
    ])
    ->whereNull('booked')
    ->delete();
}

$has_weekdays = ($r->has('weekdays')
                and !is_null($r->weekdays)
                and $ds->copy()->addDays(6)->lessThanOrEqualTo($de))
                ? true
                : false;

while ($ds->lessThanOrEqualTo($de)) {
    if ($has_weekdays and !in_array($ds->dayOfWeek, $r->weekdays)) {
        $ds->addDay();
        continue;
    }

    $ts = Carbon::create($ds->toDateString() . ' ' . $r->start_time);
    $te = Carbon::create($ds->toDateString() . ' ' . $r->end_time);

    while ($ts->lessThan($te)) {
        $count = Appointment::whereBetween('ts_start', [
            $ts,
            $ts->copy()->addMinutes(30)->subSecond()
        ])->count();

        if ($count) {
            $ts->addMinutes(30);
            continue;
        }

        $x = new Appointment();
        $x->doctor_id = $user->id;
        $x->ts_start = $ts;
        $x->ts_end = $ts->copy()->addMinutes(30);
        $x->description = "Available";
        $x->save();
        $ts->addMinutes(30);
    }

    $ds->addDay();
}

return response()->json([
    'success' => true,
    'message' => 'Schedule set up successfully',
], 200);
```

Comment: _it happens randomly_ A suggestion would be to check calls to this function in your codebase.

Comment: Yes i have checked it.This function runs when users ticks the box otherwise no calling to deletion.Could it be because of null?